# Two-stage cluster sampling problem

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, cluster-sample

I'm having difficulty understanding the following problem. It seems like it is a two stage cluster sampling problem, but then the defective red lightbulbs make the question even more difficult.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction in terms of the correct formulas to use.

Problem:

A SRS of 5 boxes each containing 60 light bulbs is selected from a warehouse containing 1000 such boxes. The bulbs are either red or green, and proportions vary across boxes. The bulbs are tested, and the green bulbs are fine but many of the red bulbs are defective. The sample results are as follows.

[image]

(a) Estimate the number of defective red bulbs in the population.

(b) Estimate the number of red bulbs in the population.

(c) Estimate the fraction of red bulbs in the population that are defective.

(d) Estimate the variance of your estimate in part (c).

(e) Estimate the design effect for the estimate in part (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorta looks like a homework problem but here's a little to get you going.

(b) Estimate the number of red bulbs in the population.

number of reds per box = (40+40+35+30+30) / 5 = (you fill this number in)   this is based on your samples.

therefore, total number of reds is:  total-reds = reds-per-box * 1000 = (you fill in this blank)

Comment: Former exam question, just wanted to know how to do it.

Comment: a) 7,000 b) 35,000 c) 1/5 or 20% 

Still working on d) and e)